# Google play publish again

Tags: google-play, publishing

I have uploaded my apk-file as release version and published it. After some time(half day) I unpublished it to fix something. Now, 1 week later, I want to publish it again.

Would it affect promotion? I heard that "new, just published" applications have more chances to get to top apps list.

So, if I publish my application again, it would be "new app", or only first publish considered?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question, because Google is deliberately inscrutable regarding anything that pertains to rankings.  You've already unpublished, so what choice do you have other than to publish again?  You could change your package ID and publish as a totally new app, I suppose.  I would not worry too much about this as this initial lift is probably not all that major but nobody knows that for certain.  Normally, one does not unpublish to fix a bug; one just fixes it as soon as possible.

Comment: My first publish was made by mistake. App was not ready at all. Ty for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not noticed any "penalty". Amount of installs per day grows as it was in first time.